# Django how to make each member of ManyToMany field unique?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm working on a recruitment website for programmers where each user can complete programming cases online and see their results.

Here is how I modeled my relationships ( I omitted many unimportant fields and kept only the interesting ones) :

Here's my candidate class

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
cases = models.ManyToManyField(Case)
```

Here's my Case class

```
class Case(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Titre", max_length=1000)
test1_complete = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Test 1 Complété", default=False)
test2_complete = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Test 2 Complété", default=False)
test3_complete = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Test 3 Complété", default=False)
test4_complete = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Test 4 Complété", default=False)
```

I then created two candidates and a case on the user panel and  linked the two users with the case through the ManyToMany field.
the test complete boolean fields refer to wether or not the user completed each set of test for the current case.

This is how I get the Case of each user in my views to modify it :

```
def fetch_cases_info(request):
first_case = Candidate.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list("cases", flat=True) 
user_case = Case.objects.get(id=first_case)
```

My problem is that each Candidate has the same Case object and thus if User1 completes test1 of the case then each User will have it set to true.

My goal is that when I make changes on a Case stored in the ManyToMany field of a Candidate it will only make the changes for this one and not for everyone using this case.

Does anyone have any idea on how to model this relationship ?
I would like every Candidate to be able to have multiple Cases but the they have should be Unique versions of a Case so that I can modify it's state and only affect one Candidate and not everyone.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManyToManyField`, unless you make it do otherwise, will create a third table to act as a joiner. This is the only way relational databases know how to make a many-to-many relationship. The `complete` boolean fields belong in this joiner table, not on any of the two many-to-many tables.

So instead, do what Django does, but manually: make a model for (e.g.) Exercise; say that every Candidate can have many Exercises, but each Exercise belongs to one Candidate; every Case is done in many Exercises, but each Exercise is of a single Case. Then stick your booleans on the Exercise table. You can then stick a ManyToManyField with `through='Exercise'` if you want, to give you the convenience access to `candidate.cases` and vice versa, now that you know what it actually does.

tl;dr: ManyToManyField is a hack. Do it manually to know what's going on (and to be able to use the joiner for fields of its own).

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with `through` parameter to ManyToManyField but I would suggest changing schema a bit. I'm making an assumption here but having a new column for each test may not be the best idea (think if you can have Cases with less or more tests in future)

```
class Case(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Titre", max_length=1000)

class TestCase(models.Model):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Candidate(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    completed_tests = models.ManyToManyField(TestCase)
```

And then to find out what tests were solved for given Case, do

```
candidate.completed_tests.filter(case=mycase)
```